# Prevent figures from closing when running a script from the command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython

When I run my code from the shell command line, it opens the figure window and displays the plot but as soon as the code is completed it closes it. I do not have any close() statements.

How can I prevent figures from closing when running a python script from the command line with ipython?

I could add a statement at the end to quit only after pressing any key, but that feels too much like a hack.

Comment: Are you running _within_ ipython, as in `In [n]: run script`  or on the shell command line _using_ ipython, as in `$ ipython script.py`?

Comment: In the shell. I will clarify in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that I needed to use plt.show() rather than plt.draw().

Answer (score 0):

I like to use

```
plt.draw()
plt.pause(0.01)
input("<Hit Enter To Close>")
```

so that I can close the plot from the command line, rather than having to click.

Comment: I didn't expect to find you here, Mr Tumnus.